# html setCustomValidity oninvalid and oninput explanation

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" pattern=".{5,}" name="el" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must Be Longer Than 5 Characters')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

so, without the `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"` part, regardless of the input the form will never be submitted because it will always show the "Must Be Longer Than 5 Characters" error, but by using `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"` everything works fine, however i don't seem to understand how oninvalid and oninput work together, if i am setting custom validity to `''` on input then how is the `oninvalid` part not overwritten everytime the user presses a key ?
i think this has something to do with how `setCustomValidity()` Works, no ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enter more than 5 characters and then click on submit, it would work. It will not work only in the cases, where the invalid event is fired at least once.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
   <input type="text" pattern=".{5,}" name="el"
         oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must Be Longer Than 5 Characters');"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

*A few basics, reference [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/):*
[`oninvalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) is triggered when the **constraints are not satisfied**.
[`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Complex_constraints_using_HTML5_Constraint_API) method is used to set the result of the validation; **an empty string means the constraint is satisfied, and any other string means there is an error**.

*Reason:*
- Once the `oninvalid` event is trigged you set the result using `setCustomValidity` to be a non-empty string.
- Now even after(changing the input value) the `pattern` condition is satisfied, the result of validation is a non-empty string.
- In your code `oninvalid="setCustomValidity('...')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`, you clear the result after each input.